# Why does my published application look fine in every browser except IE?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms

I have an asp.net app which during development was tested through chrome, IE, firefox and safari and looked consistent across all of them.

When I published the project and ran it from IIS all of them looked fine apart from internet explorer. In fact IE looks so far off what it should do that it is completely non functional. The page is all over the place, things are missing and CSS isn't working properly.

I don't know what is causing this and frankly it's a bit disturbing that after testing it could perform so badly when published and it is scaring me a little.

Comment: How can we help you without any piece of code / hint about what's going on? Check with development console (press F12) for correct script/CSS references and maybe JS errors that cause issues.

Comment: Because I am sure many people have published applications before and seen similar behaviour. Like the guy below who was kind enough to provide a constructive answer.

Comment: The point of putting the topic on hold after it has been answered is what exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By any chance is this site being accessed over an intranet - it may be being forced into compatibility mode (hit F12 for developer tools to see what version is being used for render).

You can fix this by adding a header to your response:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

You may also want to check that you are sending the correct doctype for your html.

Comment: Thanks, it was in fact intranet compatibility. I will mark as answer when it allows me to.

Answer (score 3):

You are possibly facing the fact that Internet Explorer defaults to using an old version of its engine when you are connecting on an Intranet zoned website.

You can fix it either by:

Adding the following meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Sending the following header (this example uses PHP):

```
header('x-ua-compatible: ie=edge');
```

Using the following doctype (for example):

```
<!doctype html>
```